# flutter-desktop-embedding how to build exe file

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

in [flutter-desktop-embedding](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding) , I am a windows environment, I can run it, but I don't know how to build an exe file. I want to know what to do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you `flutter build` or `flutter run` a desktop project, you're already building a .exe; that's what's being launched by `flutter run`. You can find it in the `build` directory of the project (e.g., `build\windows\x64\Debug\Runner\Flutter Desktop Example.exe` for the FDE example app).

Comment: But this is the debug file, and there will be a command line when running.

Comment: I was answering the question you asked, which didn't mention either of those things. For those, see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30672 and https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31268. It's also not suitable for deployment or production use at this point, as the project README prominently states, so it's not clear why you want a release build.

Comment: I want to use it myself, but every time I have a command line, it’s not good to watch.

Answer (score 9):

First check the build options with `flutter build -h`

Then run `flutter build windows`

Then you can find the build in the following path `\build\windows\x64\Release\Runner`

Although it is created in the release folder it is still just a debug build.

Answer (score 7):

but for distribution or run on other pc you need three files of visual studio 2019 to add in folder where you have your .exe file
files are
msvcp140.dll
vcruntime140.dll
vcruntime140_1.dll

path for these file is
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE

Answer (score 5):

You can find the `release` version of your App after running `flutter build windows` in `\build\windows\runner\Release\`

Answer (score 1):

Just run `flutter build windows`
After it is done compiling and making the executable file you will find in `build\windows\runner\Release\` your .exe file type should be listed.

Answer (score 0):

- **Flutter run** also creates an exe file
- **Flutter build windows --debug** will create an .exe file in your build\windows\x64\runner\Debug\xx.exe
- **Flutter build windows** or **Flutter build windows --release** will create an .exe file in your build\windows\x64\runner\Release\xx.exe
- you will also find .dll and data folder along with this exe file.