# How to get .exe file from my flutter desktop application?

Tags: flutter, dart, desktop-application

I have built a desktop application with flutter. Now wanna share its .exe to another person.
I have browsed for it and got some [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57032406/flutter-desktop-embedding-how-to-build-exe-file#:%7E:text=2%20Answers&text=If%20you%20flutter%20build%20or,for%20the%20FDE%20example%20app) but according to this, I couldn't found.exe file.

First I run

```
flutter build windows
```

to release .exe file.

I went through the path but it created some strange file

build\windows\x64\Debug\

and found these 3 folder:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual .exe is under `build\windows\runner\Release`. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much but you late, I already found .exe file

Comment: But how can we share a single file with others? If we share just the .exe file, it shows ```flutter_windows.dll``` missing error